# Better way to solve simultaneous linear equations programmatically in Python

Tags: python-3.x, math

I have the following code that solves simultaneous linear equations by starting with the first equation and finding y when x=0, then putting that y into the second equation and finding x, then putting that x back into the first equation etc...

Obviously, this has the potential to reach infinity, so if it reaches +-inf then it swaps the order of the equations so the spiral/ladder goes the other way.

This seems to work, tho I'm not such a good mathematician that I can prove it will always work beyond a hunch, and of course some lines never meet (I know how to use matrices and linear algebra to check straight off whether they will never meet, but I'm not so interested in that atm).

Is there a better way to 'spiral' in on the answer? I'm not interested in using math functions or numpy for the whole solution - I want to be able to code the solution. I don't mind using libraries to improve the performance, for instance using some sort of statistical method.

This may be a very naive question from either a coding or maths point of view, but if so I'd like to know why!

My code is as follows:

```
# A python program to solve 2d simultaneous equations
# by iterating over coefficients in spirals

import numpy as np

def Input(coeff_or_constant, var, lower, upper):
    val = int(input("Let the {} {} be a number between {} and {}: ".format(coeff_or_constant, var, lower, upper)))

    if val >= lower and val <= upper :
        return val
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
        exit(0)

def Equation(equation_array):
    a = Input("coefficient", "a", 0, 10)
    b = Input("coefficient", "b", 0, 10)
    c = Input("constant", "c", 0, 10)
    equation_list = [a, b, c]

    equation_array.append(equation_list)
    return equation_array

def Stringify_Equations(equation_array):
    A = str(equation_array[0][0])
    B = str(equation_array[0][1])
    C = str(equation_array[0][2])

    D = str(equation_array[1][0])
    E = str(equation_array[1][1])
    F = str(equation_array[1][2])

    eq1 = str(A + "y = " + B + "x + " + C)
    eq2 = str(D + "y = " + E + "x + " + F)

    print(eq1)
    print(eq2)

def Spiral(equation_array):
    a = equation_array[0][0]
    b = equation_array[0][1]
    c = equation_array[0][2]

    d = equation_array[1][0]
    e = equation_array[1][1]
    f = equation_array[1][2]

    # start at y when x = 0
    x = 0
    infinity_flag = False
    count = 0
    coords = []
    coords.append([0, 0])
    coords.append([1, 1])

    # solve equation 2 for x when y = START
    while not (coords[0][0] == coords[1][0]):
        try:
            y = ( ( b * x ) + c ) / a
        except:
            y = 0
        print(y)

        try:
            x = ( ( d * y ) - f ) / e
        except:
            x = 0
        if x >= 100000 or x <= -100000:
            count = count + 1
            if count >= 100000:
                print("It\'s looking like these linear equations don\'t intersect!")
                break
        print(x)

        new_coords = [x, y]
        coords.append(new_coords)
        coords.pop(0)

        if not ((x == float("inf") or x == float("-inf")) and (y == float("inf") or y == float("-inf"))):
            pass
        else:
            infinity_flag if False else True
            if infinity_flag == False:
                # if the spiral is divergent this switches the equations around so it converges
                # the infinity_flag is to check if both spirals returned infinity meaning the lines do not intersect
                # I think this would mostly work for linear equations, but for other kinds of equations it might not
                x = 0
                a = equation_array[1][0]
                b = equation_array[1][1]
                c = equation_array[1][2]

                d = equation_array[0][0]
                e = equation_array[0][1]
                f = equation_array[0][2]
                infinity_flag = False
            else:
                print("These linear equations do not intersect")
                break

    y = round(y, 3)
    x = round(x, 3)
    print(x, y)

equation_array = []
print("Specify coefficients a and b, and a constant c for equation 1")
equations = Equation(equation_array)
print("Specify coefficients a and b, and a constant c for equation 1")
equations = Equation(equation_array)
print(equation_array)
Stringify_Equations(equation_array)
Spiral(equation_array)
```

Comment: This is a well solved problem.  I think you want to look into LU decomposition with pivoting.

Comment: Yeah that's a few stages down the line for me! I wondered if there are any algorithms or number theory stuff to improve convergence - but I can accept that linear algebra is the solution to this problem

Comment: No, it is the algorithm you need if your problem is linear.  There is no convergence - it either has a solution or it does not.  If your problem is non-linear, then you have to to worry about iterative solutions, step size, and convergence.